# jqGrid programmatically Setting Total Records

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Instead of having a json object with a total attribute I have a local dataset I am trying to dynamically append to a jqGrid. Is there a simple attribute for jqGrid I can just tell what number to put for the total records? Like jqGrid.config{ datatype:'local' , total:25} ?

Comment: why do you want to specify the total number of records? why not just let your local dataset determine the total?

Comment: Cause I want server side paging, and I have literally spent the last 8 hours trying to get it to read localReaders and JsonReaders. I think my problem is these damn AngularJS directives, google hardly turns up anything involving angularjs+jqgrid.